# allocating memory using calloc and freeing

Tags: c, malloc, free

gcc 4.4.4 c89

I have a program that I am testing. I create a struct object called devname and allocate memory so that I can fill the elements. I display them and then free the memory that was allocated.

However, I am getting the following error:

```
invalid operands to binary != (have ‘struct Devices_names’ and ‘void *’)
```

That is in my for loop for displaying the structure elements. However, I feel I am testing for a NULL pointer.

Just a further question, is there an problem with the free?

Many thanks for any advice,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static struct Devices_names {
#define MAX_NAME_LEN 80
    int id;
    char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
} *devname;

static void g_create_device_names(size_t devices);
static void g_get_device_names();
static void destroy_devices();

int main(void)
{
#define DEVICES 5
    g_create_device_names(DEVICES);

    g_get_device_names();

    destroy_devices();

    return 0;
}

static void g_create_device_names(size_t devices)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    devname = calloc(devices, sizeof *devname);
    if(devname == NULL) {
        exit(0);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < devices; i++) {
        devname[i].id = i;
        sprintf(devname[i].name, "device: %d", i);
    }
}

static void g_get_device_names()
{
    size_t i = 0;

    for(i = 0; devname[i] != NULL; i++) { <-- ERROR HERE
        printf("Device id --- [ %d ]\n", devname[i].id);
        printf("Device name - [ %s ]\n", devname[i].name);
    }
}

static void destroy_devices()
{
    while(devname != NULL) {
        free(devname++);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you only have one allocation to create the whole `devname` array, you only need to check that array for `NULL`, and only need to free that one array. As you're looking through `devname`, each entry is actually a `struct Devices_names`, not a pointer, so it can't be compared with `NULL` or freed in any meaningful way. In this case, you will need a separate variable that tracks *how many* entries there are:

```
for (i = 0; i < devname_count; i++) {
    printf("Device id --- [ %d ]\n", devname[i].id);
    printf("Device name - [ %s ]\n", devname[i].name);
}

...

free(devname);
devname = NULL;
devname_count = 0;
```

Comment: When I did the following devname = calloc(devices, sizeof *devname). I thought I was creating 5 devname objects on the heap. So I would have to free all 5 of them. However, are you saying that there is only one allocated object? Thanks.

Comment: You are creating *space* for five objects, but you are only actually allocating one contiguous chunk. A good rule of thumb is that each call to `malloc()` or `calloc()` should be matched by exactly one call to `free()`.

Comment: Thanks, I will remember that. Sounds like a easy rule to follow.

Answer (score 2):

`devname[i]` is not a pointer its a `struct Devices_names`, therefore the comparison doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Where you write:

```
for(i = 0; devname[i] != NULL; i++) { <-- ERROR HERE
```

you are testing against NULL an instance of Device_names, not a pointer. It would be fine if you had an array of pointers to Device_names.

The other problem is that you are allocating only one Device_names, so you have not an array of them.

Answer (score 1):

After `calloc` you need only test for returned pointer to be not-null (and `calloc` call succeeded).

But once you `calloc`ated an array you cannot determine how many items in allocation having only pointer to it, so neither `devname[i] != NULL`, nor `devname+i != NULL` will not work, altough second will compile. Only environment or RTL know this. And this is great difference between `*alloc` allocation and static declaration (even it is of variable size as introduced in C99). So you NEED to store size of allocated array elsewhere.

Also remember, array (or any other memory chunk) allocated with single `calloc()` should be deallocated with single `free()` call with SAME pointer as returned by malloc. Passing any other pointer to `free()` cause undefined behaviaour (which is often FAIL).

So your code should be:

```
static struct Devices_names {
#define MAX_NAME_LEN 80
    int id;
    char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
} *devname;
size_t devicecount;

...

    devname = calloc(devices, sizeof *devname);
    if(devname == NULL) {
        exit(0);
    }
    devicecount = devices;

...

    for(i = 0; i<devicecount; i++) { // <-- no error more here

...

static void destroy_devices()
{
    free(devname);
}
```